# How can node.js call python code?

Tags: python, node.js

I will need to run some python scripts from my node.js code on an Amazon EC2 VPS.

Is this possible with node.js?

Comment: Is your question about AWS Node integration or the order to run external programs?

Comment: there are AWS EC2 instances running node. if you use elastic beanstalk to deploy on that instance you would be able to run any script. check http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.html and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html for more detail

Answer (score 2):

For node and Python on the same computer, there are two solutions:

(1) node can call most Python scripts using [the nodeJS child process API](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)

(2) node code can talk to Python code via sockets (either at localhost 127.0.0.1 or Unix-based) if the Python code supports sockets

Comment: what about for different computers?